# Alphabetical sorting by name - javascipt, cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need help with this code

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
import { get } from 'lodash';
 
 
const jsQuery = require('json-query');
const utils = require('../../../support/utils')
const roles = utils.roles;
const uri = Cypress.env('res_URL')
const AUT = roles.Admin;
const LONG_TIMEOUT = 10 * 1000;
 
describe('Alphabetical name sorting', () => {
 
    before(function () {
        //Log in 
        cy.login_Res(AUT.username, AUT.password)
    })
 
 
 
    it("sorting test", () => {
        cy.visit(`${Cypress.env('res_URL')}/testpage`);
 
        const checkAscSort = (value, limit) => {
            const recordsUiAsc = cy.get('#Cust').children().map(function(){ return this.label;});
            //const ascSorted = [];
 
            cy.get(value).then(rows => {
               const end = limit || rows.length;`enter code here`
                for (let i = 1; i < end; i++) {
                    const text = rows[i].innerText.toLowerCase();
 
                    recordsUiAsc.push(text);
                    ascSorted.push(text);
                }
                         const sortArray = recordsUiAsc.sort();
            expect(recordsUiAsc).to.equal(sortArray);
 
 
            });
        }
    });
 
}) //End of Spec
```

this is array cy.get('#Cust').children().map(function(){ return this.label;});
that returns all names and surnames for #Cust
but when run cypress it does not show that expect was run

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed. Where is `checkAscSort` called? The function is defined in a veriable but never called. Which is the content of its parameter `value` and `limit`. `limit` I guess is a number.

Answer (score 0):

When I call CheckAscSort than shows me cy.get...map() is not function (right is array), so there is a problem. Limit is a number rigt. When calling funtion got cy.get().children(...).map is not a function